# distributing n distinct balls on two distinct urns, so that the first urn has 1 or 3 balls and the second urn between 2 and 5 balls

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to distribute $n$ distinct balls on two distinct urns, so that in the first urn there are either $1$ or $3$ balls and in the second urn there are **between** $2$ and $5$ balls?

I know that n distinct balls can be put into $2$ distinct urns in $2^n$ ways.

Since no urn is empty, another condition is that $\frac{2^n}{2!} -1$.

But I don't know how to find a basic formula that fills the requirements.

Comment: You can't do it at all unless $3\leq n\leq8$

Comment: That is true, but assuming that $3 \leq n \leq 8$, how can one find out the ways of distributing the balls?

Comment: It's not really a matter of counting.  Once you decide how many how many balls to put in the first urn, you have to put all the rest in the second.  You have to figure out for what $n$ it's possibles to fulfill the conditions, and when you have a choice of how many balls to put in the first urn.

Comment: For n = 6, because then the first urn can definitely have 1 or 3 balls and the second urn either 5 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first urn should contain either 1 or 3 balls, and the second urn should contain between 2 and 5 balls, there should be at least 3 and at most 8 balls. You can then distinguish six scenarios for the number of balls $n$:

- $n = 3$: choose one ball for the first urn and put the remaining two in the right: ${3 \choose 1} = 3$
- $n = 4$: choose one ball for the first urn and put the remaining three in the right: ${4 \choose 1} = 3$
- $n = 5$: choose one ball for the first urn and put the remaining four in the right, or choose three balls for the first urn and put the remaining two in the right: ${5 \choose 1} + {5 \choose 3} = 5 + 10 = 15$
- $n = 6$: choose one ball for the first urn and put the remaining five in the right, or choose three balls for the first urn and put the remaining three in the right: ${6 \choose 1} + {6 \choose 3} = 6 + 20 = 26$
- $n = 7$: choose three balls for the first urn and put the remaining four in the right: ${7 \choose 3} = 35$
- $n = 8$: choose three balls for the first urn and put the remaining five in the right: ${8 \choose 3} = 56$